# Remove folders from url using .htaccess issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi So I am trying to remove `includes/pages`from a url that looks like `http://localhost:8888/london/includes/pages/soho-london-guide/` For local dev. I am using MAMP and I've enabled `mod_rewrite` too.

So far I've been trying to use different techniques and here is a list of what I've been using (trying to make it work :((( )

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^includes/pages/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

Also

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/includes/pages/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

Very very new to .htaccess and regex syntax so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: no, its in the root of the public_html

Comment: exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(?!includes/pages/)(.+)$ $1/includes/pages/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: no, its not working, i get The requested URL /includes/includes/pages/pages/soho-london-guide/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Exact same rule is working for me from site root .htaccess. When I send a request for `http://localhost/london/soho-london-guide/` it loads `http://localhost/london/includes/pages/soho-london-guide/` internally.

Comment: when i go to localhost:8888/london it redirects to soho-london-guide page

Comment: What happens when you enter this URL in browser `localhost:8888/london/soho-london-guide/` ?

Comment: it shows me the starting page. so if i go to `/london` it gives me a homepage and if i go `london/soho-london-guide` it gives me contents of homepage too

Comment: That means you have something wrong in your code/config. Can you show your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: I've got caching and expire in .htaccess this is the only rule for mod_rewrite.c module (.htaccess is quite big :)

Comment: I really cannot guess your problem without further information because this rule is working fine on my Apache.